# Shut down / descale heroku app from python

Tags: python, heroku

I have made a fast API script and want it to stop running if an event happens so it can stop the Heroku app completely and save me time of constantly checking / stopping myself. How do I do this from Python script?

Comment: can you add more details?

Comment: Python flask app deployed on my Heroku server. I use it as an API and it makes external API calls to get info using credits I have bought. With API call it gets credit amount from external source and when this amount is under X e.g 100 credits I wan't it to autoswitch off / shut down without me needing to do so. Is there a way for it to do this with heroku?